# Locating the text buried in a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, contains

I did find a lot of posts similar to mine. But i have tried a lot of suggestions and nothing seems to work :(

The web page I'm trying to scrape is 
https://m.livesoccertv.com/match/3018992/wolverhampton-wanderers-vs-arsenal/

Edit: The Channels are listed under the International Coverage Drop Down

I am looking to get the exact channel displayed on the web page with a list of partial channels held in the following line

Since the text i have in the list is not an exact match, i can't seem to get "contains" to work

I know i am missing a small tweak, but this is where i am stuck at. My variable t is what's holding me back. The web page is using the mobile link for lesser page info

Here's my code:

```
desiredChannels = ['beIN Sports HD', 'BT Sport', 'Sky Sports' 'ESPN']
channelList = []

t = '//div[contains(@class="fll b_channel_name -broadcast b_trim_inner")]'

for i in range(len(desiredChannels)):
    temp = desiredChannels[i]
    search = browser.find_element_by_xpath(t).text
    if temp in search:
        channelList.append(search)
    print(channelList)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the expected output of your print statement? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `Xpath` was a bit wrong.So I modified it.

Second thing is that the element you are looking for is `hidden` so you need to use `javaScript executor` to get the text.

Third you have total 79 elements with same `classname` so i haven taken count first then looping through the element.then only you will get desired output.

Fourth i have added `webdriverwait` in case `webdriver` taking longer to identify the element.

You need to have the following `imports` to work the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://m.livesoccertv.com/match/3018992/wolverhampton-wanderers-vs-arsenal/')
browser.maximize_window()
desiredChannels = ['beIN Sports HD', 'BT Sport', 'Sky Sports', 'ESPN']
channelList = []

t = '//div[@class="fll b_channel_name -broadcast b_trim_inner"]'
#channels=browser.find_elements_by_xpath(t)
channels=WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, t)))

for search in channels:
    searchtext=browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", search)
    for i in range(len(desiredChannels)):
        temp = desiredChannels[i]
        if temp in searchtext:
           channelList.append(searchtext)
print(channelList)
```

Output:

```
['Watch ESPN Brasil']
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: My xpath was all over the place. I had no idea where i was headed. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think the spaces in your class name are causing the problem. Try the following

```
t = "div.fll.b_channel_name.-broadcast.b_trim_inner"

for i in range(len(desiredChannels)):
    temp = desiredChannels[i]
    search = browser.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(t).text
    if temp in search:
        channelList.append(search)
    print(channelList)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should use `find_elements_xxxx()` to get all channels, rather than `find_element_xxx()` which only return the first matched one.

2) You need to click on 'International Coverage' to make channels are visible,
`.text` return empty string on invisible element.

```
desiredChannels = ['beIN Sports HD', 'BT Sport', 'Sky Sports', 'ESPN']
channelList = []

// collapse toggle 
collapse_toggle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.int_coverage > a[data-toggle]')

// expand all channels to make them visible, otherwise `.text` return empty string on invisible element
if collapse_toggle.get_attribute('class') == 'collapsed':
    collapse_toggle.click();

channels = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.int_coverage + div div.b_channel_name:not(.-country)')

for channel in channels:

    channelName = channel.text

    for desiredChannel in desiredChannels:

        if channelName.find(desiredChannel) > -1:
            channelList.append(channelName)
            break
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have tried all the 3 suggestions :) All work